# If $A=\{1,2,3\}$, $A\cup B = \mathbb{Z}$, and $A\cap B = \emptyset$, what is $B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$. Determine the elements of $B$ if $A\cup B = \Bbb{Z}$ and $A\cap B = \emptyset$.

$\mathbb{Z}$ means all integers, which means $B$ must be $\{1,2,3\}$, but the last statement says they don't have anything in common?

Comment: Hey. Why are you saying that $B$ must be $\{1,2,3\}$? If you want $A\cup B = \mathbb{Z}$, then you also need for instance $4\in B$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and if their union is the set of all integers, then $B$ is exactly the set of integers that is not in $A$.

Comment: So the answer is B = (x E Z: x<0)?

Comment: @LowStrike: no, you need to write down the set of all integers excluding $\{1,2,3\}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb Z=\{0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,...\}$

$A=\{1,2,3\}$

$A\cup B=\mathbb Z, \; A\cap B=\phi\Rightarrow B=\mathbb Z-A$

$\Rightarrow B=\{0,-1,-2,-3,\pm4,\pm5,\pm6, \cdots\}$

Answer (score 0):

B={$\pm n\;\;|\;\;n\in N\,\;,|n|\ge 4$ }$\bigcup${$0,-1,-2,-3$}

Comment: It would be great to include an explanation of how you got the answer, since a long formula is rarely a good answer on its own. The answer is also incorrect.

Comment: my mistake thnx for pointing it out